# excel vba loop max value and location more sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need the location of max value (one column) or address, so i can locate two cells left of the max value cell. next is finding the higher value of the two new cells and dividing the higher value with the max value. last step is returning the value to sheet "List1". that s the basic logic :)
thx for any help
the locating of max value and locating cells left of it, that is my main concern.

i cant figure it out. been looking for it but cant get it to work.

```
Sub DoIt()

    'ONE MAIN SHEET (List1)
    'MORE SECONDARY SHEETS WHERE DATA FOR MAX VALUE IS

    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dblMax As Double
    Dim r As Range

    i = 4
    j = 8
    g = 4
    h = 20
    s = 22

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim col, row
    Do While Cells(i, j).Value <> ""

        strSheet = Sheets(1).Cells(i, j)
        Sheets(strSheet).Activate

        'w = 2
        'e = 27
        'a = 2

        'Do While Cells(a, s).Value >= "0"
        'Range("AA1") = "IT WORKS"
        'Cells(w, e) = Cells(a, s).Value
        'a = a + 1
        'w = w + 1

    'Loop

        Set rng = Sheets(strSheet).Range("V2:V8761")
        dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

        'CODE FOR MAX VALUE LOCATION
        'LOCATING TWO LEFT CELLS OF LOCATION MAX VALUE CELL
        'DETERMINING THE HIGHER VALUE
        'DIVIDING

        Range("Z2") = dblMax    'CONTROL
        i = i + 1
        Range("Z1") = "IT WORKS"    'CONTROL

        Sheets("List1").Activate
        Cells(g, h) = "AAA"   'result of higher value cell by max value cell

        g = g + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: you can use the Excel MATCH Function to get the index of the max value, and then the INDEX or OFFSET function to get the cells to the left

Answer (score 0):

thx for help i did it. code is not refind. here is the code:

```
Sub DoIt()

Dim strSheet As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMax As Double
Dim r As Range
Dim dely As Double

i = 4
j = 8

g = 4
h = 20

l = 21

s = 22

Dim cell As Range

Dim col, row

Do While Cells(i, j).Value <> ""

strSheet = Sheets(1).Cells(i, j)

Sheets(strSheet).Activate       'error on no strsheet

w = 2
e = 27
a = 2

sumall = Application.Sum(Range("v2:v9000"))

'Do While Cells(a, s).Value >= "0"

    'Range("AA1") = "nekaj dela"

    'Cells(w, e) = Cells(a, s).Value

    'a = a + 1
    'w = w + 1

'Loop

Set rng = Sheets(strSheet).Range("V2:V9000")

dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

mmm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dblMax,     Sheets(strSheet).Range("v:v"), 0)

positionRange = Sheets(strSheet).Range("v:v")

'iii = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(positionRange, mmm)

'ooo = mmm.Offset(0, -1)
sum1 = Cells(mmm, 12)       
sum2 = Cells(mmm, 21)

If sum1 > sum2 Then

'sumall = Application.Sum(Range("l2:l8761"))

PLDP = sumall / 365

dely = sum1 / PLDP * 100
smer = "1"

Else

'sumall = Application.Sum(Range("u2:u8761"))

PLDP = sumall / 365

dely = sum2 / PLDP * 100
smer = "2"

End If

'Range("AA2") = iii
Range("AB2") = sum1
Range("AC2") = sum2
Range("ad2") = dely
Range("ae2") = sumall
Range("af2") = PLDP

Range("Z2") = dblMax    'test cell

i = i + 1

Range("Z1") = "IT WORKS"

Sheets("List1").Activate
Cells(g, h) = smer   
Cells(g, l) = dely

g = g + 1

Loop

End Sub
```